# merge nested array of object with parent object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

```js
var data = {
      food:"chicken", 
      list:[
             { name: "wings", qty: "25", price: "4,900", payment:"Cash" },
             { name: "lap", qty: "50", price: "9,900", payment: "Credit" }
           ]
      }
```

I received this data above from ajax through php laravel model relationship and i would like to use javascript or any library to convert the data in the format below.

The data below is what is desired.

```
var data = [
    { food:"chicken", name: "wings", qty:"25", price:"4,900", payment:"Cash" },
    { food:"chicken", name: "lap", qty:"50", price:"9,900", payment:"Credit" }        
]
```

Comment: Please share an attempt at solving the problem as a [mcve], and include it as an [edit] to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code of the `getList`-function might help you:

```
let getList = function(data, arrayKey, arrayName) {
 data[arrayKey].forEach(function(element) {
   element[arrayName] = data[arrayName]
 }); return data[arrayKey];
};
```

Here you can see a running example of the function above:

```js
const data = {
  food: "chicken",
  list: [{
      name: "wings",
      qty: "25",
      price: "4,900",
      payment: "Cash"
    },
    {
      name: "lap",
      qty: "50",
      price: "9,900",
      payment: "Credit"
    }
  ]
};

let getList = function(data, arrayKey, arrayName) {
 data[arrayKey].forEach(function(element) {
   element[arrayName] = data[arrayName]
 }); return data[arrayKey];
};

let result = getList(data, "list", "food");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this without lodash and with just ES6 is via `map` and `Object.assign`:

```js
var data = { food: "chicken", list: [{ name: "wings", qty: "25", price: "4,900", payment: "Cash" }, { name: "lap", qty: "50", price: "9,900", payment: "Credit" } ] }

var result = data.list.map(x => Object.assign(x, {food: data.food}))
console.log(result)
```

With `lodash/fp` this looks like:

```
var result = _.flow(_.map(_.extend({ food: data.food })))(data.list)
```

In `lodash`:

```
var result = _.map(data.list, x => _.extend(x, {food: data.food}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily solve it, by iterating over each item and adding to that object, the food object, as follows:

```
data.list.forEach((oneItem) => {
     oneItem.food = data.food;
});
data = data.list; //keep the array of list objects only
```